# Bot press chatbot is working fine is botpres editor, but failing in external website

Tags: chatbot, botpress

I made a bot which is perfectly working in Botpress editor. But facing difficulty when added to external UI.  I followed the instructions @ https://botpress.io/docs/channels/web/ . But I am getting the below error

> "13:06:59.118 DialogEngine Error processing “say
>
> ## !builtin_text-lbs0Re” Err: Content element “!builtin_text-lbs0Re” not found "

However my content Json file contains the message

> { “id”: “builtin_text-lbs0Re”, “formData”: { “text$en”: “Hey, This is
>   Nexa. I would like to help you understand N8 Basic questions”,
>   “typing$en”: true, “variations$en”: [] },

My html page looks as below - SImilar to Botpress documentation

> `    window.botpressWebChat.init({ host: http://localhost:3000/', botId: 'your _bot _id_here' })

The error i am getting is

> bp:dialog (bot) [z3AS4gXX8UuhjJ6sHfXEH] render element
>   “#!builtin_text-lbs0Re” +20s 13:06:59.118 DialogEngine Error
>   processing “say #!builtin_text-lbs0Re” Err: Content element
>   “!builtin_text-lbs0Re” not found Flow: main.flow.json Node: entry
>   [Error, Content element “!builtin_text-lbs0Re” not found] STACK TRACE
>   Error: Content element “!builtin_text-lbs0Re” not found at
>   DialogEngine._reportProcessingError
>   (/snapshot/build-mac/out/bp/core/services/dialog/dialog-engine.js:0:0)
>   at DialogEngine.
>   (/snapshot/build-mac/out/bp/core/services/dialog/dialog-engine.js:0:0)
>   at Generator.throw () at rejected
>   (/snapshot/build-mac/out/bp/core/services/dialog/dialog-engine.js:0:0)
>   at tryCatcher
>   (/Users/Downloads/botpress-v11_9_next-2019-05-21-darwin-x64/modules/.cache/module__0d92e45acb6587a48fca5bf12039dcea04d4f1f731482cc6548205bb16ee42d1/node_production_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>   at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
>   (/Users/Downloads/botpress-v11_9_next-2019-05-21-darwin-x64/modules/.cache/module__0d92e45acb6587a48fca5bf12039dcea04d4f1f731482cc6548205bb16ee42d1/node_production_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
>   at Promise._settlePromise
>   (/Users/Downloads/botpress-v11_9_next-2019-05-21-darwin

Could someone please help me to point out the error?

Answer (score 0):

Did you put your bot id?

```
window.botpressWebChat.init({ host: http://localhost:3000/', botId: 'MyBot' })
```